# Ruby freezes on getting response from socket

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, server

I've a Java Server running, and I'd like to get information from it using Ruby, but Ruby freezes upon getting the response from the Java Server. (The server knows that Ruby connected to the server and gave the server string) Why? If I turn off the server, Ruby continues and get an empty string.

Ruby client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'
sock = TCPSocket.new('some.numeric.ip', 25002)
sock.send('test\000',0)
puts sock.read #and there Ruby frezees :c
sock.close
```

Java Server (below):

```
public class kRcon{
    private static Socket socket;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Thread u;

    private static class Server extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                    int port = 25002;
                    try {
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    while(true) {
                      try {
                         socket = serverSocket.accept();
                         BufferedReader socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                         BufferedWriter socketWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                         String str = socketReader.readLine();
                    socketReader.close();
                         System.out.println(str);
                         socketWriter.write("test");
                         socketWriter.flush();
                         socketWriter.close();
                      }
                    }catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
           }
     public static void init(){
       try {
          u = new Server();
          u.setName("Server");
          u.start();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // changed
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is `socketWriter.close()` being executed? Is an IOException being thrown?

Comment: IOExpection doesn't show. But.. `socketWriter.close()` i don't know!

Comment: However, if I send socket by Java Client to this server everything works fine.

Comment: Well, hook up a debugger and find out! My best hunch here is that ruby is doing that `sock.read`, which is going to block until it returns. Now, if it failed to connect to your server, it'd probably return immediately. The fact that it hangs means that, probably, the connection is being established just fine, but Java never closes the connection, so the Ruby call never unblocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indenting is so screwed up, you don't deserve an answer.  Why? Because it will take someone 20 minutes to fix your formatting.

Your code has two problems:

1. This line: `String str = socketReader.readLine();` says to read data from the socket until a newline is encountered (a newline can be any of `"\n"`, `"\r"`, or `"\r\n"`).  Yet in your ruby program, you do this: `sock.send('test\000',0)`.  No newline anywhere in that data, so your java program patiently sits there trying to read in more data.
2. After fixing #1, your server will output the error: `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed`.  That's because `socketReader.close();` also closes the underlying socket.  Subsequently, any code that tries to use the socket, throws an error. Closing the socket in your java code will also cause the line `sock.read` in your ruby client to return without having read anything, so nothing gets output by your ruby client.

Comment: Sorry. This works, but `\n` and `\r` must be in `"..."` no in `'...'`
Thank you, for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Cody S's comment - the Ruby read call doesn't return until the TCP connection is closed.  To test this, change the Ruby read call to `sock.read(4)`.  This way the call will return when it receives 4 bytes, regardless of whether the connection is closed.

If this works, then fire up Wireshark and see if the TCP connection is being closed by the Java server.  When it comes to finding out what is being sent on the network, Wireshark is your friend.

Comment: `socketWriter.write("test"); socketWriter.flush(); socketWriter.close();`